# If condition inside a foreach loop (scanDirectory function)

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a php condition inside a foreach loop but i'm having some difficulties. I looked up in the other threads dealing with that but couldn't find a solution/explanation to apply in my code. Here it is :

```
<?php
    $directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];              // current directory
    $user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username']; // get username
    $repository = gatorconf::get('repository');   // get base repertory of the file manager
    $userdir = $repository.DS.'user'.DS.$user;   // user's repertory

function scanDirectory($userdir = ''){
    $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        echo "$folder<br />";      // line where i tried different things for my condition
        scanDirectory($folder);
    }
}
scanDirectory($userdir);
?>
```

I'm trying to replace the line `echo "$folder<br />";` by a condition so that instead of being echo'd the variable $folder would be compared to another variable before going back into the loop, like this :

```
if ($folder == $directory) {
    echo "you have permissions on this folder";
}
```

Basically the purpose of my code is to compare specific repertories with the repertory the user is currently in, and if there is a match then some html will be displayed, but I think i don't have the right approach.

Any suggestions is appreciated !

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the current directory as a parameter to the function and pass it on as you go through all folders.

```
<?php
$directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];              // current directory
$user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username']; // get username
$repository = gatorconf::get('repository');   // get base repertory of the file manager
$userdir = $repository.DS.'user'.DS.$user;   // user's repertory

function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory){
  $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
  foreach($folders as $folder){
      if ($folder == $directory) {
          echo "you have permissions on this folder";
      }
      scanDirectory($folder, $directory);
  }
}

scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works ! Would mind explaning what actually happens when you add a parameter ? Why doesn't the function just simply compare $folder to $directory with only the If condition ?

Comment: It has to do with something called [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) ([PHP variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)). Where your `$directory` variable is defined is not the same scope as where you have that if condition. You make that variable part of that scope by passing it on as a parameter.

Comment: aaah I get it ! I believe this is the exact same reason i couldn't print/echo an array defined inside `function scanDirectory` outside of this function ? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Exactly :) [return](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) lets you work with that array outside the function scope.